# Creating Trigger to Grab FullPhotoUrl from User

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm creating a trigger to pull the FullPhotoUrl from a selected user. However when bulkifying I can't get employee to show as a variable. I know I'm missing an incredibly basic mistake. Any help would be great. Here's where I'm getting caught up.

```
trigger EmployeeProfileImageHandler on SFDC_Employee__c (before update) {
SFDC_Employee__c[] employees = (SFDC_Employee__c[])Trigger.new;

Set<String> employeelist = new Set<String>();
for (SFDC_Employee__c employee : employees) {
    if(employee. != null) {
        employeelist.add(employee);            
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well assuming your code is like this (I added the field) -

```
trigger EmployeeProfileImageHandler on SFDC_Employee__c (before update) {
SFDC_Employee__c[] employees = (SFDC_Employee__c[])Trigger.new;

Set<String> employeelist = new Set<String>();
for (SFDC_Employee__c employee : employees) {
    if(employee.FullPhotoUrl__c != null) {
        employeelist.add(employee.FullPhotoUrl__c);            
    }
  }
}
```

It should be fine, if there is a specific error you are facing then do explain.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason it wasn't pulling employee as a object to allow me to use the "." to lookup a field. After reloading it, it seemed to fix itself. Very odd. I've now run into another issue but I'll open a separate question.